# Boot.img too large

Tags: build, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, android-source, cyanogenmod

I have compiled a kernel from source for the htc evo 4g. I get successfully the zImage.
So, when I build the whole tree, I use the zImage as kernel instead of the prebuilt kernel.

However when I build the whole android tree, I get the following error:

> out/target/product/supersonic/boot.img total size is 5988352
>   error: out/target/product/supersonic/boot.img too large (5988352 > [5406720 - 270336])
>   make: *** [out/target/product/supersonic/boot.img] Error 1
>   make: *** Deleting file `out/target/product/supersonic/boot.img'

Searching in web, I didn't find a solution.

I only found that the size of partitions are defined in the file `device/htc/supersonic/BoardConfig.mk`, but i don't know how to change them.

```
BOARD_BOOTIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE := 0x00280000
BOARD_RECOVERYIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE := 0x00500000
BOARD_SYSTEMIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE := 0x15e00000 # limited so we enforce room to grow
BOARD_USERDATAIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE := 0x1aba0000

BOARD_FLASH_BLOCK_SIZE := 131072
```

I don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the boot partition is limited to: 0x00528000 - 0x00042000 which is about 5MB. Thats small! modern(2013-2014) devices have 10MB-50MB

You need to make your boot.img smaller, either removing unneeded drivers from the kernel, or limiting the amount of data/binaries you compile into the ramdisk.

You can also check the actual boot.img size of your device by pulling the original boot.img partition using 'dd' command, and if its actually bigger than 5MB, you can increase the value in BOARD_RECOVERYIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE.